# Question about Joomlart uber theme and dynamic content

Tags: templates

I am using the Uber template from Joomlart. This template is a dynamic one, and upon resizing the window certain elements disappear.

However, I would not like for this to happen in certain cases. It seems to depend on what the css class is.

How can I prevent elements from disappearing using this template?

I have tried looking around some of the php/less files but have been unsuccessful. I just don't know what file to look in to prevent this sort of behavior.

Many thanks!

Comment: You have paid for this template. Please post this question on joomlaart support forum and have them assist you with this.

Answer (score 0):

you need to checkout bootstrap page where you find grid class info `http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options`. After you read this, you can edit your template or even add classes to your module class.

regards